# How can I access fitted estimators in a ColumnTransformer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I designed my sklearn pipeline in the following way:

```py
transf_pipe = make_column_transformer(
    (binning_pipe, ['na', 'nc']),
    (OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary'), ['site_type']),
    (make_pipeline(
        common_country,
        OneHotEncoder()), 'visitor_country'),
    (make_pipeline(imputing_pipe,
                    StandardScaler()
                  ), ['window', 'day_of_week', 'los']),
    remainder='passthrough',
    n_jobs=-1
)

full_pipe = make_pipeline(
    transf_pipe,
    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=3, min_samples_leaf=8), 
)
```

I called `full_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train` and all works smoothly.

However, I want to inspect some of the transformers or estimators, such as the one hot encoder, when I access it through `full_pipe.named_steps` I am not able to see the fitted attributes.  It is like the estimator was not fitted.

How can I access the fitted estimators of a pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can access steps in a [Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline) with `full_pipe.named_steps` or with indices `full_pipe[0]`.
- You can access fitted transformers in a [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer) with `transf_pipe.transformers_`.

In your example, use `full_pipe[0].transformers_[1][1]` to access the fitted OneHotEncoder.